# how can I detect the windows user's name and add it to a file path

Tags: python, windows

I am making a python script as a school project but
I have been using my own user in order to use a file path, but I want to make it so that I can use this program on other devices, please, can someone help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the os library for this.

```
import os
user_name = os.getlogin()
```

os.getlogin() returns the currently logged in user's user name as a string. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) is the documentation.

Comment: thank you, I appreciate the great answer and surprisingly fast response

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project! Consider accepting the answer if it helped you.